# R - Filter duplicate rows in large data frame

Tags: r, duplicates, unique, distinct

I have a dataframe with 500k rows and about 130 columns. I want to filter out duplicate rows for all columns except one (column 128). I tried:

```
df <- unique(df[,-128])

df <- df[!duplicated(df[, -128])]

df <- distinct(df, -column128)
```

I get the same error over and over again:

```
Error in paste(...............,  : formal argument "sep" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

I also tried to type every single column out, but got the same error. If I try the above for the first 9 columns, the error doesn't appear. However, if I try the same for 10 columns, I get the error. Is there a limit on the number of columns for removing duplicated rows? Or has anyone a solution?

The df looks as follows  (column 128 = label):

```
    data.frame':    571262 obs. of  139 variables:
 $ x                      : num  1 1 1 1 0 0 0 7 7 7 ...
 $ jan                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ feb                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mrt                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ apr                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ mei                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ jun                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ jul                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ aug                    : num  1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sep                    : num  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ okt                    : num  0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ nov                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ dec                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ - 1                    : num  0 0 1 1 1 ...
 $ - 2                    : num  0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ - 3                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ - 4                    : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
......
 $ - 114                  : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ label                  : int  8 12 8 12 8 10 12 8 10 12 ...
 $ 2008                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2009                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2010                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2011                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2012                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2013                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2014                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2015                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2016                   : num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ 2017                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 2018                   : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: hey thanks for this - please can you post the structure of your data frame? IE str(df), particularly for columns which seem to cause the error.

Comment: @OlliePerkins, I edited my orignal post for a global structure of my df.

Comment: **Seems like one of your month columns 'sep' is colliding with the argument `paste(..., sep)`**. Strange. As a workaround, rename the column.

Comment: *"However, if I try the same for 10 columns, I get the error."* Because 'sep' is your 10th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seems like one of your month columns 'sep' is colliding with the argument `paste(..., sep)`**. The error is telling you *'formal argument "sep" matched by multiple actual arguments'*.

Unlikely you have 2+ columns called 'sep' : check `which(names(df)=='sep')`

Workaround is to rename your column 'sep' to something else, e.g. 'spt'

Comment: But it's still a bug, so can you make a minimal testcase, and report it? Which function from which package is calling `paste()` anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can try a `tidyverse` solution using the `filter_at` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(14)
df <- data.frame(a=sample(1:4, 5, T),b=sample(1:4, 5, T), d=1:5) 
df
  a b d
1 2 3 1
2 3 4 2
3 4 2 3
4 3 2 4
5 4 2 5
df %>% filter_at(vars(-3), all_vars(!duplicated(.)))
  a b d
1 2 3 1
2 3 4 2
3 4 2 3
```